# why 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 returns float?

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, int

```
<?php
$i = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
var_dump($i);
```

**output** => **float(1125899906842600)**

> ### why output is a float type ?

Comment: Because 32-bit int cannot hold such value

Comment: Because PHP doesn't have a long. PHP has 32bit or 64bit integers, depending on your platform. It does not have ints *and* longs.

Comment: in which case will be used 64 bit integers ?

Comment: On a 64bit platform with PHP compiled as 64bit.

Answer (score 9):

If PHP encounter an overflow, it will cast to float.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 9):

Because 1125899906842600 > 2147483647. 2147483647 is the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer.